# How do I get the ??? Shop on Burrito Bison: Launcha Libre

Tags: burrito-bison-launcha

[image: I need help with getting to the ??? Shop on Burrito Bison: Launcha Libre.]

Can anyone help me with the ??? Shop?

Comment: Never mind! I have now got it!

Comment: What did you have to do? You should make it an answer!

Comment: Maybe you have to complete Rift level 2 to unlock it?